# Is there a better way to vstack a numpy array from an empty array, like a list array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wish to `vstack` a `numpy.array` (like building a `list`) but, I cannot  initialize the `numpy.array` with the correct shape to use `numpy.append`(`numpy.empty/zero/like_empty`, etc. did not do the trick... anyway. Finally, I figure the two pieces of code below.  Is there someyhing more pythonic? I am using python 3.6.9

```
import numpy as np
a=[]
n=4
for i in range(n):
'''
some calculation resultinng for example in an numpy.array([[i,i+1,i+2]) 
'''
        a.append(np.array([i,i+1,i+2])) 
a=np.array(a).reshape(3,n)
print(a)
```

or because I prefer to mantain it as a numpy array inside the loop:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([])
n=4
for i in range(n):
'''
some calculation resultinng for example in an numpy.array [i,i+1,i+2]
'''
    if a.size == 0: 
        a=np.array([i,i+1,i+2]) 
    else:
        a=np.vstack((a,np.array([i,i+1,i+2])))
print(a)
```

both output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]]
```

Comment: What's the problem with initializing `a` as `a = np.array([0, 1, 2])`? And what exactly is the result that you want to achieve (maybe there is a better way to do it)?

Comment: Hi Andreas K,  [0,1,2] represent a result of a calculation inside the loop then I cannot initialize it with that before start the loop. The output is the result that i am looking for. I am not a python expert and wondering if I miss a simpler way to do it.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first use, with list append:

```
In [146]: alist=[]                                                              
In [147]: for i in range(4): 
     ...:     alist.append(np.arange(i,i+3)) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [148]: alist                                                                 
Out[148]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4]), array([3, 4, 5])]
```

and make the array:

```
In [149]: np.array(alist)                                                       
Out[149]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

or since `vstack` is happy with a list of arrays:

```
In [150]: np.vstack(alist)                                                      
Out[150]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

You could use `vstack` in the loop:

```
In [151]: arr = np.zeros((0,3),int)                                             
In [152]: for i in range(4): 
     ...:     arr = np.vstack((arr, np.arange(i,i+3))) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [153]: arr                                                                   
Out[153]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

This has two problems:

- it is slower; list append operates in-place simply adding a pointer to the list.  `vstack` makes whole new array each time, with a full copy!
- it is harder to initialize, as you found out.  You actually have to understand array shapes, and what `concatenate` does when it combines 2 or more arrays.  Here I started with a (0,3) array.

Comment: Yes, the last one...speed does not matter because in my program must built  a numpy array anyway.  I didn't know before your post how to initialize an numpy.array with (0,3) shape. Great thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([np.arange(i, i+3) for i in range(n)])
```